# Issue with Monte Carlo analysis with uncertainty on LCIA

Tags: uncertainty, brightway

I try to run a Monte Carlo analysis with uncertainty on characterization factor. The code is running well (no error) but the results for each iteration are always the same. Calculation works with just LCA simulation.

Here is the code:

Definition of a sample LCIA method

```
some_exchange = bw.Database('biosphere3').random()
my_cf = [(some_exchange.key,
      {"amount": 10,
       "uncertainty_type": 4,
       "minimum": 0,
       "maximum": 20}
     )]
uncertain_method = bw.Method(("fake", "method", "with uncertainty"))
uncertain_method.write(my_cf)
```

Definition of an simple activity

```
simple_LCI_db = bw.Database('simple LCI db')
simple_LCI_db.write(
    {('simple LCI db', 'some_code'): 
        {'name': 'fake activity',
         'unit': 'amount',
         'exchanges': 
            [
                {'input': ('simple LCI db', 'some_code'),
                 'amount': 1,
                 'type': 'production'},
                {'input': some_exchange.key,
                 'amount': 1,
                 'type': 'biosphere'},                
            ]
        },

})
```

Monte Carlo code

```
mc = bw.MonteCarloLCA({('simple LCI db', 'some_code'):1}, ('fake', 'method', 'with uncertainty'))
next(mc)
```

Is there something wrong with the uncertainty definition?

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to define your `uncertainty dictionary` slightly differently: in Brightway, the `uncertainty type` is written without the `_`, i.e.

```
my_cf = [(some_exchange.key,
      {"amount": 10,
       "uncertainty type": 4, #and not "uncertainty_type"
       "minimum": 0,
       "maximum": 20}
     )]
```

You can see the schema for the `uncertainty dictionary` in the Brightway framework in the [Brightway documentation](https://docs.brightwaylca.org/intro.html#storing-uncertain-values)

You wrote it like it is defined in the `stats_arrays` [documentation](https://stats-arrays.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I do not know why they are different, i.e. why in one case we have `uncertainty type` and in the other `uncertainty_type`, but just remove your `_` and your code will work.